# React Native Navigator Route Object is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Why am I getting an error that `route` is `undefined` in my React Native Navigator component? I thought I was pushing the correct information but I guess not? Any help would be appreciated. I'm used to working with the web so React Native is quite the shift.

So...

I want to navigate from my `SplashContainer` component to my `SignUpForm` component. So in `SplashContainer` I do this...

```js
class SplashContainer extends Component {
    handleLoginFinished = () => {
        this.props.dispatch(handleAuthWithFirebase())
    }
    handleToSignUp = () => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            signUpForm: true
        });
    }
    handleToSignIn = () => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            signIn: true
        })
    }
    render () {

        return (
            <Splash onLoginFinished={this.handleLoginFinished} goToSignUp={this.handleToSignUp} goToSignIn={this.handleToSignIn} />
        )
    }
}

export default connect()(SplashContainer)
```

Then in the React Native Navigator I do this...

```js
export default class NimbusNavigator extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        isAuthed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    }
    renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
        // Keeps track of whether user is Authed or not. 
        if (this.props.isAuthed === false) {
            return <SplashContainer navigator={navigator}/>
        } else if (route.signUpForm === true) {
            return <SignUpForm navigator={navigator}/>
        }

        return <FooterTabsContainer navigator={navigator} />
    }
    configureScene = (route) => {

    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Navigator
                configureScene={this.configureScene}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route is undefined at start because you didn't give the `Navigator` any **initial routes**. You want to set either of the props [initialRoute](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#initialroute) or [initialRouteStack](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#initialroutestack).

Assuming you want to start at a route with the name HOME, here's an example where the route `{ name: 'HOME' }` is defined inline:

```
render () {
    return (
        <Navigator
            initialRoute={{ name: 'HOME' }}
            configureScene={this.configureScene}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the navigation is set up like this:

```
  handleToSignUp = () => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'signUpForm'
        });
    }
```

//

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    // Keeps track of whether user is Authed or not. 
    if (this.props.isAuthed === false) {
        return <SplashContainer navigator={navigator}/>
    } else if (route.name === 'signUpForm') {
        return <SignUpForm navigator={navigator}/>
    }

    return <FooterTabsContainer navigator={navigator} />
}
```

Comment: Route would be `undefined` either way.